# Is it possible to run Android Emulator on a Qemu virtual machine?

Tags: android, emulation, qemu, proxmox

My setup is:

- a physical machine with an Intel CPU, Debian 10 and Proxmox.
- a Windows 10 guest with Hyper-V disabled, nested virtualization enabled, Android Studio and HAXM installed.

When I launch the emulator from AVD Manager, it starts, shows the Google logo and go loading forever.

Logs and some other details are [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1564100/how-to-run-android-emulator-x86-on-windows-10-proxmox-guest).

Answer (score 0):

You can try different emulator.
BlueStack however.

Or install VM with Android.

Now In the log I don't see any critical about VM installation.

Comment: I tried to use GenyMotion and BlueStacks. Both didn't work. I guess it has something to do with me trying to run it on a Qemu guest (at least in case of GenyMotion because it uses VirtualBox under the hood). The only thing that did work, however, was switching to a Debian 10 guest.